# How to turn off auto locking of Outlook 2013 on Windows 8?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, lock

I've got a computer here with Windows 8 and I'm having an issue that whenever I leave my computer for inactivity and return back and open Outlook (which was active before) I have to enter my E-mail credentials again. However, If I close Outlook and open it, it doesn't ask for it.

Although it isn't that much of a problem, it is quite a hassle since I'm Away From Keyboard quite often.

Thanks!

Comment: This a personal or office computer?

Comment: Office computer. It's running Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: This behavior sounds like its handled by a group policy.  I would ask your IT staff about it.

Comment: Speak to your company's IT staff and see if they're applying polices. If so, they're the ones who have to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked it up on microsoft answers and it seems that one fix would be "under User Accounts, clicking reset security policies"

Comment: I actually couldn't find that option under my configuration panel..